# How do I set MyBatis configuration properties in an application.properties file in a Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis

The MyBatis [Spring Boot Starter documentation](http://www.mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/) lists properties that can be set in the application.properties file, and that list includes:

> configuration: A MyBatis Configuration bean. About available properties see the MyBatis reference page

It's not very obvious from there, but what I think it's suggesting is that you can add something like this:

```
mybatis.configuration.jdbcTypeForNull=VARCHAR
```

This seems to work; certainly, if I change `VARCHAR` for something that is not a valid value for the enum JdbcType, I get an error. However, it also doesn't appear to be picking up my setting.

When I use a debugger, I can see that `MybatisProperties.setConfiguration()` is called, *before* `Configuration.setJdbcTypeForNull()`, which means that the default value (`JdbcType.OTHER`) is used instead of the value I'm trying to set.

Am I misunderstanding how this functionality is supposed to be used, or is this a bug? Is anyone else setting config values like this? Elsewhere I can only see examples using XML files, which I'd rather avoid, if possible.

#### Well, this is embarrassing

I gave up on trying to use the `configuration` property in `application.properties`, and resorted to the XML config that I was trying to avoid, but just now, having seen some useful suggestions here, I went back to my code, changed it from the XML config back to having `mybatis.configuration.jdbcTypeForNull=NULL` and re-ran my test, which was definitely failing under the same conditions before, but now it passes.

I've no idea what's different from before - debugging I see the same behaviour as mentioned above - the Configuration bean *seems* to get the jdbcTypeForNull parameter set back to OTHER during startup, but then when it's accessed during a query it's NULL again. I'll leave this question here in case it's a race condition and it starts failing again later, but for now my problem seems to have mysteriously disappeared.

Comment: Have you tried adding this `<setting name="callSettersOnNulls" value="true"/>` to your `mybatis-config.xml` which will allow you to get null or empty values without errors.

Comment: Isn't this setting for when you're getting nulls out of the database? The case I'm looking at is setting columns to null in an insert.

Comment: My mistake I was consfused. Are you using bean as the parameterType.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use `mybatis.configuration.jdbcTypeForNull`, please remember  NOT to specify `configLocation` property at same time. Otherwise your setting will be erase to default.

As what spring boot do, `MybatisProperties.setConfiguration()` is called before `Configuration.setJdbcTypeForNull()` is really right. Because spring boot try to set `configuration` to `MybatisProperties` but found its member `configuration` is null, so spring boot will instantiate a new `Configuration` and assign it to `MybatisProperties` immediately. Afterwards, spring boot will try to assign all `mybatis.configuration.*` to this member of `MybatisProperties`.

If you are going to use XML to configure mybatis, you need specify `<setting name="jdbcTypeForNull" value="VARCHAR"/>` under element `<settings/>` as [example](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/zh/configuration.html#settings).

This would definitely work.

Comment: Is this something that you've seen work? I get an error message: "Field error in object 'mybatis' on field 'configuration.jdbcTypeForNull': rejected value [12] ... nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.apache.ibatis.type.JdbcType.12]".

Comment: Please check `JdbcType` and find the real value you want.

Comment: No, that's not it. You can see in the error message that it's trying to use the ...ibatis.type.JdbcType. As I say in the question, using VARCHAR does set the value correctly, but it is then re-set with a default after it gets set.

Comment: Ok. I got it. I'm on the train and replying you with my phone and it's not easy to read the source. I'll leave any message if I could.

Comment: `Configuration#setJdbcTypeForNull()` has been called after `MybatisProperties#setConfiguration()` is correct. Cause later should be mapped to what you have configured when it is needed . Spring will create a default `Configuration` and assign it to `MybatisProperties` and then set `JdbcTypeForNull` properly. Are you sure the value isn't what you've configured?

Comment: Please see my answer and I've updated it. I think it could help.

Comment: Thanks, that's a helpful answer, and certainly does seem to be the effect I'm seeing, I'm just confused about why the first time I did it the new value didn't seem to be used when it created the query. For now I'll put it down to user error on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Add this `<setting name="jdbcTypeForNull" value="OTHER"/>` to your `mybatis-config.xml` it should work fine. Else try this to your query which works perfectly fine for me with oracle/mysql as db

```
   insert into students 
     (id,name,class,date_of_joining)
     values 
     (#{id,jdbcType=INTEGER},#{class,jdbcType=TIMESTAMP},
     #{class,jdbcType=NVARCHAR},#{date_of_joining,jdbcType=TIMESTAMP})
```

Here is [list of jdbcTypes](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/apidocs/reference/org/apache/ibatis/type/JdbcType.html) provided by mybatis. You need to add it to each constraint if you feel the constraint can be empty/null at times.

Comment: OTHER is the default, and that's what doesn't work (with Oracle). I am currently using this, but setting it to ...value="NULL", which works. The point of the question though was about not using the XML config if possible. My problem seems to have gone away now though - see edit to my post.

Comment: Are you using bean as the parameterType in your mapper xml.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using application.yml try

```
mybatis:
  configuration:
    jdbc-type-for-null: 'NULL'
```